# Do you have a custom active admin index page builder?

Tags: activeadmin

I would like to build a custom index page for ActiveAdmin.

I don't mean the records shown in the index or the list of columns to display -- I mean a custom view as described here:

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/docs/3-index-pages/custom-index.md

A Google and SO search does not turn up any code samples. I have looked at the Active Admin code itself -- but also wanted to see some examples.

Ideally, I would be able to reuse the filter and scope and table components that the index provides -- I simply want to move things around quite a bit and add a custom component or two.

Anyone have any pointers or examples?

Answer (score 1):

activeadmin has nice wiki page here https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki/Plugins

there u can find at least several implementation of custom index components
for instance

- https://github.com/bys-control/activeadmin-index_as_calendar
- https://github.com/zorab47/active_admin-sortable_tree

And of course take a look at sources

- https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/index_as_grid.rb
- https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/index_as_table.rb
- https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/index_as_blog.rb
- https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/views/index_as_block.rb

You can try to inherit from one of them and add your own missed parts, depends on your needs